# Can I use two voltage regulators connected in series?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, voltage-regulator, parallel, series

For my project I'm using 2 regulator, 8V (UBEC) and 5V (LM2596). What is a better idea, connect them in series or parallel?

[image]

Comment: Where both is feasible, choose by thermal considerations.

Comment: The question is not clear. You have not included the part number of the 8-volt converter. And the schematic is not making much sense :(

Comment: What is each regulator powering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can, the 5V regulator accepts as low as 7V on its input, and this makes the 5V side safer in case the 5V regulator fails, as the maximum voltage would be no more than 8V, and likely less than that. This would make the higher voltage regulator run at a higher current, so overheating could become an issue at higher power levels. 
You would get slightly higher efficiency or lower energy losses by running the 5V regulator directly from 12V since these are both switching regulators.

It's different if one of them is a linear regulator; typically commercial devices will use a switching regulator for the higher voltage, followed by the linear regulator which is less efficient but would be dropping less voltage across it, significantly reducing power losses but most importantly it is done for the purpose of achieving a cleaner, less noisy voltage on the lower output.

If both of them were linear, the **total** losses would be the same, but you would want to run them in parallel to spread the losses and thus heat more evenly, otherwise one of them could be overheating, it all depends on the amount power being expected on each output. 
Again, the same thing applies regarding the series connection being safer for the lower voltage devices, as they would be exposed to a less extreme increase in voltage if their regulator fails short.

The resistor schematic below is meant as an equivalent for linear regulators at a 1A current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV03j0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: OP says LM2596, which is a dcdc buck. Same for the UBEC.

Comment: Yes, and I have mentioned that in my answer, but I was answering the more generic question in the title, which many people will be lead to when asking such question, so I have covered both situations. The resistor schematic is meant as an equivalent for linear regulators at a 1A current.

Answer (score 0):

You can run them in series. Your efficiency will be lower since your 5V rail will have losses in the 8V regulator as well. If both at are about 80%, then stacking them will make your overall 5V efficiency as:

- 80% x 80% = 64%

Further, the LM2596 efficiency by itself is somewhat lower (by a few %) with Vin at 8V vs. 12V. See the data LM2596 datasheet.

This arrangement does have the benefit of ensuring your 5V supply will never be higher than your 8V. You get power sequencing / interlock ‘for free’ (except it costs you efficiency.)

On the other hand if you run them in parallel, take note of your power sequencing to ensure that your 5V and 8V power rails come up in a way that is acceptable to your system.

Usually this means that your 8V should have a ‘power ok’ signal that would then switch on the 5V. If it doesn’t, you could create one by monitoring the 8V rail. The LM2596 datasheet shows an example of an undervoltage lockout that could do that.

Comment: That 80% figure didn’t come out of thin air. The LM2596 datasheet shows 80% efficiency at 3A with 12V in.  It drops to 77% at 8V, making double-regulation an even less desirable choice, efficiency-wise.